# Using iptables, I lose connection. After flushing, connection is back

Tags: linux, iptables

These are the commands I am using when I loose my connection.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0

sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*iptables*' documentation about [*NFQUEUE*](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-extensions.8#NFQUEUE) tells:

> `--queue-bypass`
>
> By default, **if no userspace program** is listening on an NFQUEUE, then
>   **all packets that are to be queued are dropped**. When this option
>   is used, the NFQUEUE rule behaves like ACCEPT instead, and the packet
>   will move on to the next table.

So that means that you are supposed to be running a program receiving packets sent through this queue, but there is no such process running.

Here's a link explaining how to use NFQUEUE, including sample code (that can't be used as-is):

[To Linux and beyond ! Using NFQUEUE and libnetfilter_queue](https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/using-nfqueue-and-libnetfilter_queue/)

Note that some functions used in the example are [deprecated](https://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/doxygen/html/group__Queue.html).

Meanwhile, if you don't want to loose connectivity while setting up such program or tool but errors happen, you can just add the option `--queue-bypass` like this (but it might make sense to use different queues depending on implementation):

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 --queue-bypass
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 0 --queue-bypass
```

Alas as is that means your filter's *INPUT* and *OUTPUT* chains would be completely bypassed since *NFQUEUE* would behave as *ACCEPT*, while the *NFQUEUE* process has the possibility to reinject the packet for further processing by using the verdict *NF_REPEAT* and marks, as described for example in this other link from the same blog:

[Building a suricata compliant ruleset](https://home.regit.org/2011/01/building-a-suricata-compliant-ruleset/)